# R grouping by name and perform stats (t-test)

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe, text-mining

I have two data.frames:

```
word1=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b")    
word2=c("a","a","a","a","c","c","c")
values1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
values2 = c(3,3,0,1,2,3,4)
df1 = data.frame(word1,values1)
df2 = data.frame(word2,values2)
```

df1:

```
  word1  values1
1   a      1
2   a      2
3   a      3
4   a      4
5   b      5
6   b      6
7   b      7
```

df2:

```
 word2  values2
1   a     3
2   a     3
3   a     0
4   a     1
5   c     2
6   c     3
7   c     4
```

I would like to split these dataframes by `word*`, and perform two sample `t.test`s in R.

For example, the word "a" is in both data.frames. What's the `t.test` between the data.frames for the word "a"? And do this for all the words that are in both data.frames.

The result is a data.frame(result):

```
   word  tvalues
1   a    0.4778035
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the words common to both dataframes, then loop over these words, subsetting both dataframes and performing the `t.test` on the subsets.

E.g.:

```
df1 <- data.frame(word=sample(letters[1:5], 30, replace=TRUE),
                  x=rnorm(30))

df2 <- data.frame(word=sample(letters[1:5], 30, replace=TRUE),
                  x=rnorm(30))

common_words <- sort(intersect(df1$word, df2$word))

setNames(lapply(common_words, function(w) {
  t.test(subset(df1, word==w, x), subset(df2, word==w, x))
}), common_words)
```

This returns a list, where each element is the output of the `t.test` for one of the common words. `setNames` just names the list elements so you can see which words they correspond to.

Note I've created new example data here since your example data only have one word in common (`a`) and so don't really resemble your true problem.

---

If you just want a matrix of statistics, you can do something like:

```
t(sapply(common_words, function(w) {
  test <- t.test(subset(df1, word==w, x), subset(df2, word==w, x))
  c(test$statistic, test$parameter, p=test$p.value, 
    `2.5%`=test$conf.int[1], `97.5%`=test$conf.int[2])
}))

##            t        df          p       2.5%      97.5%
## a  0.9141839  8.912307 0.38468553 -0.4808054  1.1313220
## b -0.2182582  7.589109 0.83298193 -1.1536056  0.9558315
## c -0.2927253  8.947689 0.77640684 -1.5340097  1.1827691
## d -2.7244728 12.389709 0.01800568 -2.5016301 -0.2826952
## e -0.3683153  7.872407 0.72234501 -1.9404345  1.4072499
```

Comment: But how to create a data.frame (table) with just the p-values? ex: "e" "0.2731", following your data.frames values. Thanks